# Paypal PHP SDK with laravel. Problem loading config endpoint in production mode

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-rest-sdk

I try to use the Paypal PHP SDK with laravel. 
Everything works fine in Sandbox mode.
But when i go live i have a problem of config loading when the request come back after paiement on paypal platform.

My problem is on this file /lib/PayPal/Handler/RestHandler.php, $config is empty

```
private function _getEndpoint($config)
{
if (isset($config['service.EndPoint'])) {
    return $config['service.EndPoint'];
} elseif (isset($config['mode'])) {
    switch (strtoupper($config['mode'])) {
    case 'SANDBOX':
    return PayPalConstants::REST_SANDBOX_ENDPOINT;
    break;
    case 'LIVE':
    return PayPalConstants::REST_LIVE_ENDPOINT;
    break;
    default:
    throw new PayPalConfigurationException('The mode config parameter must be set to either sandbox/live');
    break;
    }
    } else {
    // Defaulting to Sandbox
    return PayPalConstants::REST_SANDBOX_ENDPOINT;
    }
    }
```

My problem is that the config is not loaded here.

I did this in my laravel app : Add a config file paypal.php

```
<?php
return [
    'settings' => array(
        'mode' => env('PAYPAL_MODE','LIVE'),
        'service.EndPoint' => env('PAYPAL_ENDPOINT','https://api.paypal.com/'),
        'http.ConnectionTimeOut' => 30,
        'log.LogEnabled' => true,
        'log.FileName' => storage_path() . '/logs/paypal.log',
        'log.LogLevel' => 'ERROR'
    ),
];
```

I handle my ApiContext like this in a PayPalController

```
public static function generatePaypalApiContext(Connexion $connexion)
    {
    if (isset($connexion->data["paypal_client_id"]) && isset($connexion->data["paypal_client_secret"])) {
    $apiContext = new ApiContext(new OAuthTokenCredential($connexion->data["paypal_client_id"], $connexion->data["paypal_client_secret"]));
    $paypal_conf = config('paypal');
    $apiContext->setConfig($paypal_conf['settings']);
    Session::put('paypal_api_context', $apiContext);
    } else {    
    return false;
    }

    return $apiContext;
    }
```

and this is my function to execute the paiement

```
public static function getPaymentStatus(string $payerId)
{
    /** Get the payment ID before session clear **/
    $payment_id = Session::get('paypal_payment_id');
    /** clear the session payment ID **/
    Session::forget('paypal_payment_id');
    $apiContext = Session::get('paypal_api_context');
    $payment = Payment::get($payment_id, $apiContext);
    $execution = new PaymentExecution();
    $execution->setPayerId($payerId);
    /**Execute the payment **/
    $result = $payment->execute($execution, $apiContext);
    if ($result->getState() == 'approved') {
    return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

What's wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way. Passing the Api context to my PayPalController::construct() and stop to use functions in static.

Answer (score 0):

Is this a new integration? If so, the v1 PayPal-PHP-SDK is old and deprecated and should not be used for anything.

Instead, use the v2 [Checkout-PHP-SDK](https://github.com/paypal/Checkout-PHP-SDK)

Comment: i use this version https://packagist.org/packages/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php

Comment: The problem is : i have to handle billing agreement as well (only available in V1)

Comment: Why do you have to handle a billing agreement using the old SDK? You should probably be using direct HTTP calls for that portion. The new Subscriptions API, for example, is not supported by any SDK.